# Regex Python For Numbers/Words

Tags: python, regex

I have to match strings in python 2.7 which are of the format - 
{2 digit day of the month} {the exact words de or del} {4 digit year} 
and replace this entire substring of the string with only
{2 digit day of the month} {4 digit year} and remove the word de/del. 
I know about word boundaries (\b) and I have tried this:

```
s4 = "la fecha de hoy es septiembre 31 de 1958 and tom fecha septiembre 
30 de 1958"
s4 = re.sub(r'((\b\d{2}\b)[de,del](\b\d{4}\b)', "\\1 \\3", s4)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How does your attempt fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[de,del]` does not match what you think it does. This notation is used for a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). If you want to match `de` or `del`, you can write this as `del?`

There is a whitespace between `31 de` and `de 1958`. You could match that as `\s` or if there are more `\s+` or just a whitespace itself.

I think you don't need the outer capturing group. That way where will be just 2 capturing groups which will be used in the replacement.

For this match I think you don't need the word boundaries `\b`, but if you want to keep them you could update your regex to:

[`(\b\d{2}\b)\s+del?\s+(\b\d{4}\b)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZwSC66/1)

[Demo](http://rextester.com/GLG32718)

Answer (score 0):

`[de,del]` matches one of the following chars: `del,`

You want to use `del?` ("de" with maybe an "l" at the end)

And if you want to match whitespace use `\s`, I prefer to use this than `\b`

Comment: `\b` does something else than `\s`; it does emphatically *not* "match whitespace". OP's code is correct for when punctuation or end-of-line follows the number; your `\s` would fail in such, and similar, cases.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the information, but `\s` matches `\n`.

Comment: Yes, but it does not match an explicit end of string such as afetr `end` in `here is the end`.